# How do you find the optimal box size when given only the amount of material used?

Tags: calculus, optimization

I'm learning calculus 1 and I've gotten to the section on optimization. All of the questions that involve finding the optimal volume of a box set one of the dimensions to be defined in terms of another (for example they might say length and width of the Box are equal.) I understand it's probably beyond the scope of my current knowledge but I was wondering how one actually would find the optimal box dimensions to maximize volume without these restrictions.

Comment: I could give an example: a box must have a volume of 32000 cm^3. Find the dimensions of the box that minimize the amount of material used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let $$a,b,c$$ are the side lenths of the given box, then we have $$abc=32000cm^3$$
and the material that we need is given by $$M=2(ab+bc+ac)$$
can you finish?
applying $$AM-GM$$ inequality we get
$$2(ab+bc+ac)\geq 6\sqrt[3]{32000cm^3}$$ the equal sign holds if $$a=b=c$$

Comment: I cannot, the only way I've learnt to optimize involves taking the derivative of one variable against another, which means I have to Define all my variables in the end as one of two options

Comment: do you know the $AM-GM$ inequalitiy?

Comment: No, I haven't heard of that.

Comment: it is $$\frac{x+y+z}{3}\geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$$ if $$x,y,z\geq 0$$

Comment: I found a Wikipedia page on it I'm working  at it now

Comment: ok after this i will give you a hint for the solution,ok?

Comment: Much appreciated. I guess I should clarify that this is not for school or anything, I'm doing this on my own.

Comment: I'm guessing I'm going to have to end up using the chain rule here somehow

Comment: ´no we will use the inequality above!

Comment: And take the derivative in terms of what?

Comment: Hold on the comment sectionas not meant for extended discussion we should open up a chat if you want to do this extended teaching method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69643/discussion-between-user2624102-and-dr-sonnhard-graubner).

Comment: yes i have inserted the answer in my post

Comment: Thank you, I shall delete my criticism.

Comment: i wish you a nice sunday